# Move dependent jars to Worker Node

Tags: java, apache-spark

I've one spark program and within that am using some external jars too. After writing a program, created a jar from maven build and will submit to spark.

Have one doubt, I've 5 node cluster.

Once I submit my spark code jar to spark-submit, then Do I need to copy my dependent's jar too to worker nodes ?

May I know please how movement of dependent jar works ?

Answer (score 1):

Pass required jar file list separated by `:` to spark config properties `spark.driver.extraClassPath` &  `spark.executor.extraClassPath`.

Required jars will be copied to both master & worker nodes.

```
spark-submit \
--conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=/lib/<jar_file_a>.jar:/lib/<jar_file_a>.jar" \
--conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=/lib/<jar_file_a>.jar:/lib/<jar_file_a>.jar" \
[...]
```

Comment: Will this copy main jar and dependent jars to Worker nodes ?

Comment: What's diff between driver.extraClassPath and executor.extraClassPath ?

Comment: driver.extraClassPath copies jar to driver & executor.extraClassPath copies to executors, please check here for more info on this - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

Comment: My spark code jar is driver jar. Correct ? And executor jars are all other dependent jars. Correct ?

Comment: not like that..your code will be executed in driver & executors.. inside your code if you are using any third party jars & if you want available those jars at runtime at both driver & executors .. you can use both options.

Comment: So in driver.extraClassPath, which jar's path I'll give ? And In driver.extraClassPath, Which jar's path I'll give ?

Comment: if you want you can put same jar files in both driver & executor configs

Comment: Im sorry, but you have confused me :(

Comment: Tell me in this way, I've my spark code jar named as MySparkCode.jar and that jar is using some 3rd party jars too. Lets say A.jar, B.jar and C.jar Now tell me what will be me config in two parameters you have mentioned

Comment: You can simply pass all jars like this - --conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=MySparkCode.jar:A.jar:B.jar:C.jar" \
--conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=MySparkCode.jar:A.jar:B.jar:C.jar" \ ..

Comment: What's benefit of using same jars in both parameters ?

Comment: Your spark code might need dependency jars , Most of your classes are going to execute driver & executors.. lets say if you are not passing A.jar to executor & your spark code is depending on that jar might fail in executors.